# Does anyone knows how to fix LOCKDOWN_E_INVALID_HOST_ID on sideloadly windows?

Tags: sideloading

i'm trying to use sideloadly on my windows pc to sideload api on my ipad which is in iOS 16.1. But i keep having this error :

FAILED: Call to lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake failed: LOCKDOWN_E_INVALID_HOST_ID
ERROR: Guru Meditation 6020bc@99:f11511 Call to lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake failed: LOCKDOWN_E_INVALID_HOST_ID

I read on sideloadly website that it's happens when i dont trust computer from iDevice but i trusted it so i dont understand.

I tried with itunes from apple website, from sideloadly website and microsoft store, it didnt fix anythng. Also tried to change USB port. I have the same issue on my ihpone. It was working corretly a few months ago but not anymore.